# Workaround for #request.getParameters() in Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf, cas

We are using CAS 5.2.3 which uses an upgraded version of Thymeleaf. Thymeleaf has restricted access to certain request features - '#request.getParameters()' being one. Is there any work around for it? I am getting the following error when trying to access it - "Access to request parameters is forbidden in this context. Note some restrictions apply to variable access. For example, direct access to request parameters is forbidden in preprocessing and unescaped expressions, in TEXT template mode, in fragment insertion specifications and in some specific attribute processors."

Comment: Faced with the same issue. Didn't find anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question. I face this problem a few months before, it is solvable.

After looking through their source code, I found that they are limiting the usage of `#request.getParameters()` only on specific tag, they didn't forbid to use `#request.getParameters()` in some situation.

In my use case, I am able to use CData to bypass this checking. Not sure whether it applies to your use case since you didn't provide any code example....

---

Anyway, the below example want to redirect user to another page, based on the parameter `url`

*Here's an sample code that was broken in CAS 5.2.x, but worked in CAS 5.1.x :*

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Deforestation </title>
</head>
<body th:attr="onload='window.location.href=\''+${#request.getParameter('url')}+'\''">
</body>
</html>
```

*Here's a work around code:*

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Deforestation </title>
</head>
<body>

Logging out. Please wait...

<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    location.href = /*[[( ${#request.getParameter('url')} )]]*/ ;
/*]]>*/
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If this didn't solve your problem, please provide your source code so we can have a better look at the problem.

---

Note: There is a security reason why this stuff is now banned, using this workaround might compromise the security standard, do remember to sanitize the user input if neccesary

---

### Edit:

as per comment, although not elegant, maybe something like the following will work?

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Data attribute </title>
</head>
<body>

<span id="foobarid"> </span>

<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    $('#foobarid').data('foo-bar',/*[[( ${#request.getParameter('foo') == 'bar'} )]]*/); 
/*]]>*/
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am trying to set a data attribute. Here is the piece of code which is proving to be a problem:
 `th:data-foo-bar="${#request.getParameter('foo') ==  'bar'}"`
Another work around would be to set its as a request attribute or in the session context. Please let me know your thoughts on it.
Please let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: See the updated answer, I don't have my work computer on hand so didn't test the code. Try and see if the edited answer works~

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed the work flow to set the property as a session attribute instead of setting it as a request parameter. It's working now.

Comment: If you feel this answer is useful, can you help marl this as accepted answer and upvote the question, thanks!

Comment: Just tried the answer to verify. To be clearer with the question that I asked, I wrote the following piece of code to get it to work:
`<script th:inline="javascript">
            <![CDATA[$('#div-id').data('foo-bar', [${#request.getParameter('foo') == 'bar')}]);
            ]]>`

Answer (score 1):

Apparently one can spend hours, even days on this simple requirement, which Thymeleaf introduced as a poorly dcumented annoyance in later versions. I've spent hours upgrading from an older Thymeleaf version from 5 years ago and got stuck on this very same problem. The lack of documentation didn't either. When I finally took a think break, I've realized the solution to this problem is as simple as using the <c:set> core tag with JSP.

Simply use the `th:with` tag in some higher level html tag where accessing request parameters is allowed, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
  th:with="action=${param.action != null ? 
                    param.action[0] : 'none'}">
<head>
...
```

In this example, the request parameter `action` is stored in a page context local variable named `action` (the name can be any unique name that you choose). This variable is now accessible anywhere bellow your high level html tag where you've defined it. It can even be used in following `th:xx` tags in the same html tag after the declaration. So basically, now you can do this:

```
<th:block th:switch="${action}">
    <title th:case="'edit'" th:text="#{page.contacts.edit}"></title>
    <title th:case="'delete'" th:text="#{page.contacts.delete}"></title>
    <title th:case="*" th:text="#{page.contacts.add}"></title>
</th:block>
```

and even call a parameterized fragment by simply referring to your variable as `${action}`. In this example I have a navbar template fragment, which accepts three parameters. The last of which, is a request parameter that otherwise, is inaccessible due to the newer Thymeleaf request object access restrictions.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="nav" th:replace="html/fragments/navbar ::
         navbar('html/contact','contact-html', ${action})">
    </div>
<div class="content">
...
```

If you need more request params and more local page context variables, just use a comma to separate the declarations in the `th:with` tag like this:

```
th:with="action=${param.action == null ? 'none': param.action[0]}, 
         self=${param.self == null ? 'none': param.self[0]}"
```

I hope this saves you guys some precious time and voids the frustration of refactoring older Thymeleaf html pages. It definitely beats those horrifically unmanageable `CDATA` scriptlets inside your pages.