# Access to request parameters is forbidden in this context

Tags: thymeleaf

I am using Thymeleaf version 3.0.11. I am trying to get the query string and the url together to append another query string and redirect. Here is my code:

```
<a th:href="@{${#request.requestURL} + ${#request.queryString} + '&sort=subject'}" th:text="#{teach.subject}"></a>
```

Also tried this:

```
<a th:href="${#request.requestURL.append('?').append(#request.queryString).append('&').append('&sort=subject')}" th:text="#{teach.subject}"></a>
```

But it gives me:

**Access to request parameters is forbidden in this context. Note some restrictions apply to variable access. For example, direct access to request parameters is forbidden in preprocessing and unescaped expressions, in TEXT template mode, in fragment insertion specifications and in some specific attribute processors.**

I have also tried this:

```
<a th:href="@{${#request.requestURL} + ${param} + '&sort=subject'}" th:text="#{teach.subject}"></a>
```

And got this:

**Access to variable "param" is forbidden in this context. Note some restrictions apply to variable access. For example, direct access to request parameters is forbidden in preprocessing and unescaped expressions, in TEXT template mode, in fragment insertion specifications and in some specific attribute processors.**

Why am i not allowed to reach query string in href? I have tried th:with but results are the same. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52592892/workaround-for-request-getparameters-in-thymeleaf ?

Comment: I did but that gave me the same error too. No matter where i define it, in <a> tag or somewhere else like "th:with" tag, i get the same error everywhere.

Comment: the th:with solution is correct, just pay attention to the details. I've answered it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68340803/1272886

Comment: defining the th:with on a higher level tag like you mentioned solved the problem. You should write this as the answer so that i can accept it. Thx.